# How do I deploy a process to JBPM from a development server to production

Tags: deployment, jbpm

I have been building a process in jBPM 6.1 on a development server that I now wish to deploy to a production server.

The entire process has been created within kie workbench, eclipse has not been used in the process at all.

The process has Guided Decision Tables, Forms and Data Objects. It is not solely a BPMN2 process. I have read similar questions that suggest just importing the BPMN2 process file but this excludes the forms, GDT etc.

So far I have exported the jar file from the dev server, using the download option for the project found under Authoring > Artifact Repository. I imported that jar into the production server, which was successful.

The project does not show up in the repository under Project Authoring. If I use the 'Deploy a New Unit' option found under Deploy > Process Deployments with the correct group / artifact / version the process is deployed and I can start it.

I want to know, is this the correct method for exporting from the development server and import (and deploying) on the production server.

I have read up a lot about using maven to deploy. I am not familiar at all with maven at this stage and preferably want to avoid having to learn that simply to export / deploy the project from one server to another.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your project on a new environment do the following:

1. Clone the repository of your project locally using git.
2. On the production server, create a repository with the same name and clone it locally as well.
3. Copy the content of the first cloned repository (development) to the empty repository that you cloned in step2.
4. Now add all new files to git and commit then push and your project should now show under project authoring as soon as you browse the correct repository

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use KIE-server for your production while workbench is only for modelling, rules, etc.

This is what I have done to our project and we have been running since last year. Looks everything ok for me.

We use 6.5 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make use of the git repository only in the development environment. Once the development is completed, download the artifact using **Authoring >> Artifact Repository >> Download** and download the kjar.

Then open the kie workbench of the target environment (TEST/UAT/PROD) and follow these steps,

1. Navigate to **Authoring >> Artifact Repository >> Upload** and upload the kjar downloaded from the Development server.
2. Navigate to **Deploy >> Process Deployments >> New Deployment Unit** and specify the GroupId, ArtifactId and Version of the kjar that is uploaded and click on **Deploy Unit** to deploy the artifact to the kie-server.

This ensures that development happens only in the development server and the binary from development environment can be moved to rest of the environments for testing.